# Visual Studio C# 2008: Code Folding Problem when Typing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-folding

I have the following problem with code folding:  if I have a class with folded methods, and I insert code in between these methods, the lower code unfolds automatically.  E.g.:

```
class A
{
   void Method1() [ folded ]

   void Method2() [ folded ]

   void Method3() [ folded ]
}
```

If I insert code between Methods 1 and 2, the following happens in the midst of typing:

```
class A
{
   void Method1() [ still folded: good ]

   void Method4( [I typed until here and pause]

   void Method2()
   {
      [ unfolded by VS... do not want this! ]
   }

   void Method3()
   {
      [ more auto unfolding... ugh! ]
   }
}
```

Is there an option to disable the "smart" auto-unfolding done by Visual Studio?  I just want to insert Method 4 and keep Methods 2 and 3 folded.  As a result of the auto-unfolding, I have to manually fold Methods 2 and 3 again.

I suspect when I typed the open bracket, VS tries to look for a close bracket, but I can't find any option to disable bracket-matching.

Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint/Trick/Workaround : You could start off by typing the closing bracket first.
This is Usually how I avoid unfoldind code when I want to comment blocks (start by the closing tag '* /' at the end of the desired block, and then only insert my opening tag '/ *'

Comment: You can also try to select the block that you want to comment and press: Ctrl + K followed by Ctrl + C to comment the code and Ctrl + K followed by Ctrl + U to uncomment.

Comment: Yes that's what I usually do, except for large blocks where code readability is burdened by all these '//' at the beginning of each line.